# Android Virtual Device not opening on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I run my AVD using following command.

```
emulator -use-system-libs -avd Android7
```

Earlier it used to run, but now its not working at all. Now I get following error after running the command.

```
[139685110036288]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib

Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
```

Can someone please suggest something to work around or fix it permanently?

Comment: It works.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646563/cannot-start-android-emulator-from-cmd-line-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this solution from the link : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235461
and it worked!